# Android how to calibrate touch screen programatically

Tags: android

Is there any way to calibrate touch screen programatically?
Thankyou

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html go through this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched on this, then I understand that there is no API for doing screen calibration. If I found any API in future I will definitely update this.

Answer (score 0):

on my device there is a special calibration activity. You can call it with this code:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("org.zeroxlab.util.tscal", "org.zeroxlab.util.tscal.TSCalibration");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mActivity.startActivity(i);
```